# BaseJdbcLogger queryStack multi thread not safe

Tags: debugging, logging, thread-safety, mybatis, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

1. i have opend sql debug log by adding: logging.level.com.***.mapper=debug
2. then two thread in one request execute query separately by: Mono.zip(selectA(session),selectB(session)).flatMap(insertC(session))
3. occur exception like this [ArrayindexoutOfBoundsException:-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViC6L.png)
4. my version is mybstis-3.5.7

except: BaseJdbcLogger queryStack thread safety, Thanks

Comment: We need a small repro project like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues). And, if necessary, the exact steps for how to reproduce the exception.